# UIPickerView data from Parse objects

Tags: ios, parse-platform, uipickerview

In my app I am showing a picker view to let the user select one object to populate a text field.
When the user changes the picker row, the textfield should show the title of the picker row, but it doesn't happen always. 
This is the code to get the source objects from Parse:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"menu_categories"];
[query whereKey:@"category_restaurant" equalTo:restauranteID];
[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        _pickerData = objects;

        for (int i =0; i< [objects count];i++)
        {

            NSString *textoactual = self.menu_item_category_textfield.text;
            if ([[[objects objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"category_name"]
                 isEqualToString:textoactual])
            {
                [self.room_picker reloadAllComponents];
                [self.room_picker selectRow:i inComponent:0 animated:YES];
                break;

            }

        }

    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"error");
    }
} ];
```

I am using the for statement to make it possible that the picker row to be first shown is the same as the textfield content. That works fine.
But later if the user changes the picker row, the row title name that should be shown as the textfield text doesn't change properly, sometimes it does, but sometimes it doesn't.

These are the implemented picker view delegate methods:

```
- (int)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}



// The number of rows of data
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _pickerData.count;
}


- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    PFObject *object = _pickerData[row];

    self.menu_item_category_textfield.text = object[@"category_name"];
    return object[@"category_name"];



}


-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
      inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{



}
```

What should I change to obtain the desired behaviour, that means to show always the selected picker view row title as text in the textfield?

EDITED:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: where are you calling the query? and is the issue the pickerView data isn't there or the title just doesn't append in the textfield?

Comment: @soulshined, I am calling the query in the viewDidLoad method. The picker view data are ok, the issue is that the title doesn't append correctly in the textfield, but sometimes not always. There are 10 objects.

Comment: @soulshined, I have included three screenshots from the app to demonstrate what am I saying....

Comment: You could do the checking and selection in titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your doing the query in `viewDidLoad` that would be a good place to create the `NSArray` for your `UIPickerView`, this ensures its loaded in memory. My guess is by creating a new `PFObject` every time the `titleForRow:` gets called, something gets lost in translation.

So force load your _pickerData into memory:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"menu_categories"];
    [query whereKey:@"category_restaurant" equalTo:restauranteID];
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            _pickerData = [objects valueForKey:@"category_name"];
....
}
```

Then all you have to do in `titleForRow:` :

```
- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return self.pickerData[row];
}
```

And when you select it thats when you should be doing the appending **not** in `titleForRow:`

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component { 
     self.menu_item_category_textfield.text = self.pickerData[row];
}
```

Comment: I think this is a good answer.  Was just writing up something similar.  Two suggestions (1) reloadComponents explicitly **and unconditionally** (which I think is the main problem with the original code) in the completion block, and (2) handle the OP's requirement to set the picker selection based on what's already in the text field.

Comment: Thank you, every OK with your answer.

Comment: @danh good points, actually, i think your answer would be a better fit for the OP. I don't want to steal your thunder - i overlooked the pre-selected row, so go ahead and do your thing :)

Comment: :-) I'm happy to see it as a case of great minds thinking alike.

Comment: @mvasco would you like me to revise for pre-selected row, or do you have it under control?

Comment: @soulshined, your proposal fits 100% my needs. I am using it on other view controllers in my app and it works fine as you proposed.